# Wrong result when pass html select value to use with timezone_set

Tags: php, html

I'm making a little system for our team that generate some titles for use in tickets. I'm having a problem with the final expression here:

```
$horaBrasilAgora = $horaEntrada;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dubai");
$horaLocalidadeAgora = date('H');

$diferenca = $horaLocalidadeAgora - $horaBrasilAgora;
return $diferenca;
```

The above result is OK, it returns "7". But, if I take the timezone_set by a variable that comes from HTML select value, it returns incorretly.

```
$horaBrasilAgora = $horaEntrada;

date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$horaLocalidadeAgora = date('H');

$diferenca = $horaLocalidadeAgora - $horaBrasilAgora;
return $diferenca;
```

It returns "4". Here is my select html form:

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="timezone">Fuso Horário</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="timezone" name="timezone" class="form-control">
    <option value="Asia/Dubai">Abu Dhabi</option>
    <option value="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires">Arroyo Seco</option>
```

[...] and rest of code. I think the problem may be with the "value" field, where I don't know if the "/" can be the problem.

I'm really confuse about what's happening.

Comment: `var_dump($timezone)`?

Comment: Hey. I didn't get any results because that's a function inside another PHP (different from index) that is called after form submit. So, if I type var_dump I get nothing on screen (index.php)